# htaccess rewrite is giving me 500 error?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have this url that i wanted to make friendly, using rewrite on .htacess but it gives me an error(500 internal server error), this is my orginal php url

```
http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?topic=lovetopic
```

i want to change it to this:

```
http://www.example.com/lovetopic
```

this is my whole htaccess code is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /viewprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /viewtopic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

i dont know what the problem is

**EDIT** the server error log is giving me this error

```
[Thu Oct 14 20:34:36 2010] [error] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,
```

Comment: i put what the server error log is giving me up, thanks :))

Comment: since i put the rewrite for the topic url, its been giving me these 500 internal errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern of your second rule `^([^/]*)$` does also match `/viewtopic.php` without the path prefix `/`, i.e. `viewtopic.php`. That’s why you’re having an infinite recursion.

You can use the following condition to exclude that:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=viewtopic.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /viewtopic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

Or use this condition to exclude all existing files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /viewtopic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

Or use this rule in front of you other rules to stop every request that can be mapped to an existing file being rewritten by any following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: D'oh, I just checked... no, `[L]` doesn't prevent internal redirects from causing all rules to be reprocessed on the new url.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: No, the [ *L* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) is a little bit different: “Remember, however, that if the RewriteRule generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first RewriteRule.”

Comment: thank you this works, :)), the problem is i have a file called home.php which is the homepage, and the system thinks its a topic rather than the homepage? :)) if you know what i mean, so what rule should i use lol :))

Comment: @getaway: You may want to use the third example he posted before your existing rules.  This will prevent what you see now (P.S. Deleted my answer, 'cause it was wrong)